# Trouble installing WaoN, Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: compiling, make, libraries, makefile

Discovering WaoN for converting soundfiles to midi, I cloned the git repository https://github.com/kichiki/WaoN and attempted to compile it.

I had some errors and installed the necessary (or so I thought) libraries:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ymlw.jpg

+

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rm0hy.jpg

and then ran:

```
make -f Makefile.waon
```

but got some errors. I did a search and ran:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-dev-i386
```

which solved some errors, but when I ran

```
make -f Makefile.waon
```

and my output was still:

```
gcc -Wall -m32 -O3 -ffast-math `pkg-config --cflags fftw3` 
`pkg-config --cflags sndfile` -o waon main.o notes.o midi.o 
analyse.o fft.o hc.o snd.o -L/usr/local/lib `pkg-config --libs fftw3`
`pkg-config --libs sndfile` -lm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfftw3
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsndfile
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile.waon:39: recipe for target 'waon' failed
make: *** [waon] Error 1
```

When I run make clean the output is:

```
user@user:~/Music/waon/WaoN$ make clean
rm -f *.o *~ *.core \
waon \
pv \
gwaon

user@user:~/Music/waon/WaoN$ make -f Makefile.waon
gcc -Wall -m32 -O3 -ffast-math `pkg-config --cflags fftw3` `pkg-config 
--cflags sndfile`   -c -o main.o main.c
gcc -Wall -m32 -O3 -ffast-math `pkg-config --cflags fftw3` `pkg-config 
--cflags sndfile`   -c -o notes.o notes.c
gcc -Wall -m32 -O3 -ffast-math `pkg-config --cflags fftw3` `pkg-config 
--cflags sndfile`   -c -o midi.o midi.c
gcc -Wall -m32 -O3 -ffast-math `pkg-config --cflags fftw3` `pkg-config 
--cflags sndfile`   -c -o analyse.o analyse.c
gcc -Wall -m32 -O3 -ffast-math `pkg-config --cflags fftw3` `pkg-config 
--cflags sndfile`   -c -o fft.o fft.c
gcc -Wall -m32 -O3 -ffast-math `pkg-config --cflags fftw3` `pkg-config     
--cflags sndfile`   -c -o hc.o hc.c
gcc -Wall -m32 -O3 -ffast-math `pkg-config --cflags fftw3` `pkg-config 
--cflags sndfile`   -c -o snd.o snd.c
gcc -Wall -m32 -O3 -ffast-math `pkg-config --cflags fftw3` `pkg-config 
--cflags sndfile` -o waon main.o notes.o midi.o analyse.o fft.o hc.o     
snd.o -L/usr/local/lib `pkg-config --libs fftw3` `pkg-config --libs 
sndfile` -lm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfftw3
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsndfile
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile.waon:39: recipe for target 'waon' failed
make: *** [waon] Error 1
```

So I am slightly confused.

I assume the most important part is:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfftw3
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsndfile
```

To me the libraries seem to be installed, or is this incorrect based on the pictures of synaptic?

Any help is much appreciated!

Edit1:

I read something about symlinks, and have tried looking for lfftw3 by using find, but I don't understand what would be wise to do next:

```
user@user:~/Music/waon/WaoN$ sudo find / -name *fftw3*
[sudo] password for user: 
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
/usr/include/fftw3-mpi.h
/usr/include/fftw3q.f03
/usr/include/fftw3-mpi.f03
/usr/include/fftw3.f
/usr/include/fftw3.f03
/usr/include/fftw3.h
/usr/include/fftw3l.f03
/usr/include/fftw3l-mpi.f03
/usr/share/doc/libfftw3-dev
/usr/share/doc/libfftw3-mpi-dev
/usr/share/doc/libfftw3-bin
/usr/share/doc/libfftw3-mpi3
/usr/share/doc/libfftw3-single3
/usr/share/doc/libfftw3-quad3
/usr/share/doc/libfftw3-double3
/usr/share/doc/libfftw3-dbg
/usr/share/doc/libfftw3-long3
/usr/share/doc/libfftw3-3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3f.so.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3l_omp.so.3.4.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3_omp.so.3.4.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3q_omp.so.3.4.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3_mpi.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3f_mpi.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3_omp.so.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3f_omp.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3f_threads.so.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3.so.3.4.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3f_threads.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3f.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3_mpi.so.3.3.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3_threads.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3.so.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3f_omp.so.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3q_threads.so.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3_threads.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3l.so.3.4.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3q_threads.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3q_omp.so.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3_threads.so.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3l_omp.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3l_mpi.so.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3l_mpi.so.3.3.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3_mpi.so.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3l_threads.so.3.4.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3q_threads.so.3.4.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3f_omp.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3f_mpi.so.3.3.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3l_threads.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3q.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3l.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3f_mpi.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3_mpi.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3l_omp.so.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3q_omp.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3l.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3l_mpi.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3q.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3q.so.3.4.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3l_threads.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/fftw3f.pc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/fftw3q.pc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/fftw3l.pc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/fftw3.pc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3l_threads.so.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3f_omp.so.3.4.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3f_mpi.so.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3_omp.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3f.so.3.4.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3l.so.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3l_mpi.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3f_threads.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3f_threads.so.3.4.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3l_omp.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3f.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3q_threads.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3_omp.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3q_omp.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3_threads.so.3.4.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3q.so.3
/var/cache/apt/archives/libfftw3-3_3.3.4-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/libfftw3-dev_3.3.4-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/libfftw3-dbg_3.3.4-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/libfftw3-mpi-dev_3.3.3-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/libfftw3-bin_3.3.4-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/libfftw3-mpi3_3.3.3-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/libfftw3-quad3_3.3.4-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/libfftw3-long3_3.3.4-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfftw3-single3:amd64.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfftw3-double3:amd64.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfftw3-long3:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfftw3-single3:amd64.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfftw3-mpi3:amd64.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfftw3-quad3:amd64.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfftw3-long3:amd64.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfftw3-bin.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfftw3-quad3:amd64.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfftw3-bin.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfftw3-3:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfftw3-dbg:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfftw3-mpi3:amd64.triggers
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfftw3-long3:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfftw3-long3:amd64.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfftw3-mpi3:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfftw3-dev:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfftw3-dbg:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfftw3-quad3:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfftw3-quad3:amd64.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfftw3-long3:amd64.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfftw3-double3:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfftw3-double3:amd64.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfftw3-quad3:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfftw3-single3:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfftw3-single3:amd64.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfftw3-single3:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfftw3-mpi-dev.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfftw3-double3:amd64.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfftw3-mpi3:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfftw3-double3:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfftw3-dev:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfftw3-mpi-dev.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfftw3-3:amd64.list
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should install some development packages with headers and pc-files:

```
sudo apt-get install libfftw3-dev libsndfile1-dev \
libao-dev libsamplerate0-dev libgtk2.0-dev libncurses5-dev
```

Then clone repository and run `make`:

```
git clone https://github.com/kichiki/WaoN.git
cd WaoN
make
```

After these steps `waon` and `gwaon` executables were created.